# Prevent notepad window to move one position to another and maximize in windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

How to prevent notepad window or any other window to move from position to other by using drag drop? How to prevent window from maximize?

Comment: The only way I know would be to write software or use software that allows for this.  By default its not possible to prevent a user from moving a window.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the feature that triggers when you drag a window into the side or top of the screen? Or to disable moving and re-sizing any window period?

To disable the snap feature:

Go to Control Panel -  Ease of Access Center - Make the mouse easier to use

You'll want to check the box "Prevent windows from being automatically arranged when moved to the edge of the screen"

I'm not sure you can completely disable moving or re-sizing all windows. What is the reason you would need to do this? Maybe there is another way to achieve your goal if you give us more info.

Comment: I read the question as asking for the latter (that is , completely disabling moving the window) which would require third party software since there is no way to disable it otherwise.  *I do not know of any software that does this*.